# How to define an integer variable in networkx for a graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to draw an empty graph with n number of nodes. 
I tried

```
e = nx.Graph() 
for i in range (0,n):
    e.add_node(n)
```

I tried adding `n == int`

I get this error `TypeError: 'type'` object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Your problem is that each time through the loop, you're adding node `n`, rather than node `i`.

Comment: Even if you change to `e.add_node(i)`, your code can be improved...  For example in python `range(0,n)` is the same thing as `range(n)`.

Comment: And networkx has a command `add_nodes_from` which can add multiple nodes at once.  So your loop could be replaced by `e.add_nodes_from(range(n))`.

Comment: @pumpkinpeach Please stop tagging all of your questions with [anaconda], [jupyter], and [spyder] unless they specifically have something to do with those environments. These general questions apply to any Python environment or REPL, so should be left general. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import networkx as nx
n = 10
e = nx.Graph() 
for i in range (n):
    e.add_node(i)

nx.draw_networkx(e)
```

Output:

[image]